# ValueError: probabilities contain NaN

Tags: python

I'm trying to write functions for LSTM Neural network using no library except numpy and getting error will exporting the txt file.

```py
def ExportText(output, data):
    finalOutput = np.zeros_like(output)
    prob = np.zeros_like(output[0])
    outputText = ""
    print(len(data))
    print(output.shape[0])
    for i in range(0, output.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0, output.shape[1]):
            prob[j] = output[i][j] / np.sum(output[i])
        outputText = np.random.choice(data, p=prob)    
    with open("output.txt", "w") as text_file:
        text_file.write(outputText)
    return
```

```
ExportText(output, data)
```

I expect to get the predicted output txt file.But instead getting the error: ValueError: probabilities contain NaN

Comment: Well... do they? (Maybe you're dividing by 0.)

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you could try:

```
if not (np.isnan(prob[j])):
    outputText += np.random.choice(data, p=prob)
```